# pandas - Resampling datetime index and extending to end of the month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample a datetime index into hourly data. I also want the resampling until the end of the month.

So given the following `df`:

```
data = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
rng = ['Jan-2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Mar-2016']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=rng)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

            0  1
2016-01-01  0  1
2016-02-01  2  3
2016-03-01  4  5
```

I know I can resample this into an hourly index by: `df = df.resample('H').ffill()` However, when I call the `df` it gets cut at `2016-03-01`. I am essentially making the index run from `1/1/2016` to `3/31/2016` with an hourly granularity.

How can I extend this to the end of the month `2015-03-31` given that the last index is the beginning of the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [37]: (df.set_index(df.index[:-1].union([df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)]))
   ....:    .resample('H')
   ....:    .ffill()
   ....:    .head()
   ....: )
Out[37]:
                     0  1
2016-01-01 00:00:00  0  1
2016-01-01 01:00:00  0  1
2016-01-01 02:00:00  0  1
2016-01-01 03:00:00  0  1
2016-01-01 04:00:00  0  1

In [38]: (df.set_index(df.index[:-1].union([df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)]))
   ....:    .resample('H')
   ....:    .ffill()
   ....:    .tail()
   ....: )
Out[38]:
                     0  1
2016-03-30 20:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 21:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 22:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 23:00:00  2  3
2016-03-31 00:00:00  4  5
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [40]: df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
Out[40]: Timestamp('2016-03-31 00:00:00')

In [41]: df.index[:-1].union([df.index[-1] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)])
Out[41]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Old incorrect answer:**

```
In [77]: df.resample('M').ffill().resample('H').ffill().tail()
Out[77]:
                     0  1
2016-03-30 20:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 21:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 22:00:00  2  3
2016-03-30 23:00:00  2  3
2016-03-31 00:00:00  4  5
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. However I'm making an edit to the question. Unfortunately the starting index also became the end of month. I'm trying to make the index's range from 1/1/2016 - 3/31/2016

Comment: @kobrakai, yes, you right. I have updated my answer - please check

Comment: Thanks MaxU. I'm reading about the `union` and `pandas.offset.MonthEnd` functions you used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late for this, but I think this way is easier:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
rng = ['Jan-2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Mar-2016']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=rng)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Create the desired time range
t_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31', freq='h'))
# Resample
df_rsmpld = df.reindex(t_index, method='ffill')
```